# Setting default value as custom sequence

Tags: go, go-gorm

Question regarding the declaration of primary key with default value.

Using cockroachDB, we can create sequence to basically have ID starting from 1, with regular increment of 1.

[create sequence for cockroachdb](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-sequence.html)

Trying to create my model with default value `nextval('sequence_name')`

> `gorm:"DEFAULT:nextval('sequence_name')"`

Tried this one above, but it's not working (edited)

Comment: Have you tried `\`sql:"DEFAULT:nextval('sequence_name')"\`` By changing the tagging from gorm to sql

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I also need 
`gorm:"many2many:relationship_table;"`